# When to uncomment server root in apache configuration?

Tags: debian, apache2, debian-jessie, debian-stretch

I had a server upgraded from Debian 8 to Debian 9 and there are some odd or different behaviors relating to the hosted website and applications.
I'm going through and looking at various config files and the differences between them before and after the upgrade. My hosting company performed the upgrade using a script and I believe they went with the standard settings on all files that had differences. I spent quite a bit of time fine-tuning the server awhile back but I no longer have access to most of my notes relating to those tasks. I believe I need to make several small adjustments again (and lots and logs of Google searches).

My question is this: when is it appropriate to uncomment out the apache server root in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`?

Before the upgrade it was not commented out and now it is. Thank you.

Edit: I am on a dedicated VPS with several vhost files set up.

Answer (score 2):

In Apache httpd like many other applications, the **default value** will be used for any and all values that are not set (and commented out is the same in that regard) so you can safely comment out values that are :

- set to their default value (set at compile time)

In Apache httpd, when you use name based virtual hosting, the first VirtualHost will in many regards replace the main server. So:

- many of the settings that would apply to the main server become irrelevant when you have VirtualHost entries.

Comment: So you're saying that since I have several vhosts set up including the primary domain, unsetting the server root value would have no affect/be pointless since I have a dedicated VPS? Also in my case, it seems like regardless if I had set values, the default values are now present.

Comment: Probably but that depends on the full config. But what happens in an upgrade depends on context which makes it hard to explain *”why?”*